# terraform iterate over loop but not all elements but specific ones

Tags: terraform

I have an array of objects, and wanted to iterate only over specific objects (above this section in the resource there is count used fyi)

```sh
variable "x" {
  default = [
    first = [
      {
        a = 1
      },
      {
        b = 2
      }
    ]
    second = [
      {
        c = 3
      },
      {
        d = 4
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have that array above as input, and wanted in the resource to loop only over elements from 'second' section, is there some way to do so ?

`for_each = lookup(myvar, second)` ?

or as I'm using, count and looping over the names `['first', 'second']` anyway in other section,

```sh
count         = length(var.names)
name          = "${element(var.names, count.index)}"
```

maybe I can reference that to get the right elemenets from the array ?

```sh
for_each = lookup(x[lookup(element(var.names, count.index))])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix the syntax for your `x`:

```
variable "x" {
  default = [ 
    {
    first = [
      {
        a = 1
      },
      {
        b = 2
      }
    ]},
    {
     second = [
      {
        c = 3
      },
      {
        d = 4
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

then you can locate the `second` as follows:

```
locals {
  key_to_find = "second"
  index_of_the_key = index(flatten([for v in var.x : keys(v)]), local.key_to_find)
}
```

Having the index you can iterate over the `second` values:

```
flatten([for elem in var.x[local.index_of_the_key]: elem])

# or 

flatten(values(var.x[local.index_of_the_key]))
```

which will produce the following list:

```
[
  {
    "c" = 3
  },
  {
    "d" = 4
  },
]
```

Comment: literal God, was scrapping my head so long to get it, and flatten was the solution &_&, thanks mate